# Highcharts first point is not displayed

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a problem with my Highcharts : sometimes the first point appears, but sometimes he doesn't.

First point is here : 
[image: Image with first january]

First point is not here [image]

First point is here with a different zoom :

[image]

Anyone knows what part of Highcharts creates this problem?

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing code that causes this perceived issue.

Comment: There is a lot of code for this graph. I try to know what part of the code I need to change to solve the problem (YAXIS, XAXIS, plotOptions ...).

Comment: It may be caused by dataGrouping, read more [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping).